# IOS Contacts framework, how to encode and decode imageData into String and send it via infoDiscovery dictionary with MPC advertiser

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, swift2, multipeer-connectivity

I'm using **IOS Contacts Framework** to retrieve the **imageData** of the iPhone user's contact. If the **imageData** is available, I retrieve it and need to **encode** it into a String. This is because I'm using **Multipeer Connectivity Framework** and I would like to display an image beside the peer's display name in the list of browsed peers. I'm sending the encoded **imageData** through the **discoveryInfo** dictionary parameter of the **MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser** class upon initialisation.

To achieve this I've tried encoding the **imageData** using **UTF8** and **Base64**, but both failed.

This is the code I've tried for the **UTF8** encoding process:

```
// Retrieve user image and initials from global userContact variable  

func retrieveUserImageAndInitials() -> Dictionary<String,String> {  
    let userFirstNameInitial = "\(userContact.firstName[userContact.firstName.startIndex])"
    let userLastNameInitial = "\(userContact.lastName[userContact.lastName.startIndex])"

    if userContact.imageData != nil {
        print("Image data found")

        if let dataString = NSString(data: userContact.imageData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String! {
            print("Image data encoded successfully")
            return ["firstNameInitial":userFirstNameInitial, "lastNameInitial":userLastNameInitial,"imageData":dataString]
        }
        else {
            print("Image data encoded with failures")
            return ["firstNameInitial":userFirstNameInitial, "lastNameInitial":userLastNameInitial]
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Image data not found")
        return ["firstNameInitial":userFirstNameInitial, "lastNameInitial":userLastNameInitial]
    }
}
```

And this is the code for decoding using **UTF8**:

```
func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {  
    foundPeers.append(peerID)

    let userInitials = info!["firstNameInitial"]! + info!["lastNameInitial"]!

    if let dataString = info!["imageData"] {
        print("Data string found")

        if let imageData = dataString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            print("Image data fetched succesfully!")
            imagesOfFoundPeers.append(UIImage(data: imageData)!)
        }
        else {
            print("Image data not fetched")
            imagesOfFoundPeers.append(imageFromText(userInitials,
                font: UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 24.0)!, maxWidth: 50.0, color: UIColor.mainColor()))
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Data string not found")
        print("Image with initials used instead")
        imagesOfFoundPeers.append(imageFromText(userInitials,
            font: UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 24.0)!, maxWidth: 50.0, color: UIColor.mainColor()))
    }

    delegate?.foundPeer()
}
```

While using **UTF8** encoding, the String I get from the encoding process prints as nil, so the code never even gets to send it through the **advertiser**.

This is the code I've tried for the **Base64** encoding process:

```
// Retrieve user image and initials from global userContact variable
func retrieveUserImageAndInitials() -> Dictionary<String,String> {
    let userFirstNameInitial = "\(userContact.firstName[userContact.firstName.startIndex])"
    let userLastNameInitial = "\(userContact.lastName[userContact.lastName.startIndex])"

    if userContact.imageData != nil {
        print("Image data found")

        let dataString = userContact.imageData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

        print("Image data encoded successfully")
        return ["firstNameInitial":userFirstNameInitial, "lastNameInitial":userLastNameInitial,"imageData":dataString]

    }
    else {
        print("Image data not found")
        return ["firstNameInitial":userFirstNameInitial, "lastNameInitial":userLastNameInitial]
    }
}
```

And this is the code for decoding using **Base64**:

```
func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?)
{
    foundPeers.append(peerID)

    let userInitials = info!["firstNameInitial"]! + info!["lastNameInitial"]!

    if let dataString = info!["imageData"] {
        print("Data string found")

        let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: dataString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
        let userImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        print("Image data fetched succesfully!")
        imagesOfFoundPeers.append(userImage!)

    }
    else {
        print("Data string not found")
        print("Image with initials used instead")
        imagesOfFoundPeers.append(imageFromText(userInitials,
            font: UIFont(name: "Pacifico", size: 24.0)!, maxWidth: 50.0, color: UIColor.mainColor()))
    }

    delegate?.foundPeer()
}
```

While using **Base64** encoding, the code does encode the data into a String, but the app terminates because the dictionary **discoveryInfo** containing the String that resulted from the encoding process is considered an invalid argument for the MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser.

It throws the following message:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid discoveryInfo passed to MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser'`

This is the initialisation of the **MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser** and all of the **MPCManagement** objects:

```
override init()
{
    super.init()

    userContact = retrieveUserContact()

    peer = MCPeerID(displayName: userContact.fullName)

    dataSession = MCSession(peer: peer)
    dataSession.delegate = self

    deviceBrowser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peer, serviceType: "dummy-mpc")
    deviceBrowser.delegate = self

    deviceAdvertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peer, discoveryInfo: retrieveUserImageAndInitials(), serviceType: "dummy-mpc")
    deviceAdvertiser.delegate = self
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or what other option do I have for encoding and sending that imageData?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())

Comment: Don't send that sort of data in discovery info. Make the connection THEN send the data to your peer

Comment: @ChrisH I know, the string generated from the base64 encoding is too long for the discoveryInfo dictionary, but I would love to be able to display the image beforehand. It's kind of like the magic of the app :P I could try, as Jasper Bryant-Greene said, creating a custom discovery class with Bonjour, but I'm a bit green in that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Base64 would have been the correct approach to take, as it can encode arbitrary binary data. Your code is correct, although I would not use the `IgnoreUnknownCharacters` option in the decoder, as there is no reason unexpected characters would be introduced and so this setting could hide bugs from you. UTF-8 would never have worked, as it is not an encoding scheme for arbitrary binary data.

Your code is failing because the `discoveryInfo` dictionary has constraints on the size of key-value pairs.

From the [documentation of MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserClassRef/):

> *info*
>
> A dictionary of key-value pairs that are made available to browsers.
>   Each key and value must be an NSString object.
>
> This data is advertised using a Bonjour TXT record, encoded according
>   to RFC 6763 (section 6). As a result:
>
> - The key-value pair must be no longer than 255 bytes (total) when
>     encoded in UTF-8 format with an equals sign (=) between the key and
>     the value.
> - Keys cannot contain an equals sign.

You could work around this by severely reducing the resolution of the image, but the resulting image would likely be unrecognisable. You could also split the image across multiple dictionary keys, but this would probably cause very poor discovery performance due to the amount of data you would be trying to transfer over DNS TXT records.

You may want to consider transferring the image data *after* you have set up the peer connection, rather than as part of discovery. Alternatively, you could build your own discovery mechanism on top of Bonjour, as suggested in the documentation:

> If the data you need to provide is too large to fit within these
>   constraints, you should create a custom discovery class using Bonjour for
>   discovery and your choice of networking protocols for exchanging the
>   information.

Comment: Okay, so my only acceptable option is to make my own discovery mechanism on top of Bonjour. The thing is, I'm a bit green in Bonjour. Could you recommend some material or reference that I could use to learn and make this mechanism?